# iOS how to print the equivalent of "view memory of * " in xCode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsdata

I'm trying to print out the "Issuer" data available from a keychain item in iOS. I can't seem to find the proper encoding or understand how this data is stored.

When I choose thew "view memory of*" option in xCode, I see that I see some text among garbage. **I'm trying to understand how I can print both the text and garbage that the memory pointer is addressing.** Below is a screenshot of what I'm trying to do

[image]

[image]

I tried these, but I get either nil strings, or japaneese characters for UTF16

```
        id data = [innerObject objectForKey:@"issr"];

        NSString* string8 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString* string16 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
        NSString* string16be = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding];
        NSString* string16le = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
        NSString* string32 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];

        NSString* string8Bytes = [[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:&data length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//NSLog the result
```

Comment: You could try NSASCIIStringEncoding - but I'm not sure that gets you what you actually want.  It's possible you want to write your own custom loop through the bytes of data, interpreting characters manually.

Comment: no string encoding will do what you want since there are null bytes. you would need to use something like `NSScanner` so you can output some "blank" value for the null bytes and not have the string "terminate".

Comment: Ascii encoding worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the memory dump, you can select the letters and it will highlight the corresponding memory bytes. There are 2 bytes per letter, which made me realize it was using Ascii encoding, the code below works:

```
              @try {

                if([data isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]==NO)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                NSString* stringAscii = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];


                NSCharacterSet* alphaNumeric = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890.@"];


                NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [alphaNumeric invertedSet];
                NSString* cleanedUpString = [[stringAscii componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @" "];

                if(cleanedUpString.length>0)
                {
                    DLog(@" %@ Cleaned up: %@",key,cleanedUpString);
                }
            }
            @catch (NSException *exception) {

            }
            @finally {

            }
```